# Permit only numbers and "K" character in a input

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, numbers

I have a Javascript function to permit only numbers in a input.

```
<input name="onlynumbers" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);">
```

This is my Javascript function:

```
function isNumber(e) {
            k = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if (k==8 || k==0) return true;
            search = /[0-9]/;
            n = String.fromCharCode(k);
            return search.test(n);
        }
```

But now I need to permit numbers and also "K" character. I was trying to modify it but I couldn't get it.

May you help me please?

Thanks you! :)

Comment: i think you can use /[k-K 0-9]/ , adding the character to the regex, not sure.

Comment: **K**  has charcode 75. now you can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add K to search:

```
search = /[0-9K]/;
```

if you also need lowercase k:

```
search = /[0-9kK]/;
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of getting just numeric keystrokes, I've been using  this function which I didn't originally create, but found somewhere:

```
function blockNonnumericKeystrokes(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
        prorate();
        return;
    }
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use this regex `/\d+|k/i` - That regex accepts `k` and `K`, if you only want number and uppercase `K` then remove the incase sensitive flag `i`: `/\d+|k/`
- The attribute `e.key` is the pressed key

```js
document.querySelector('[name="onlynumbers"]').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (!/\d+|k/i.test(e.key)) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input name="onlynumbers" type="text">
```

## Resource

- [`keypress event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)